# gdb not working properly in windows

Tags: c++, windows-7, gdb, g++, cygwin

I created a simple cpp file and compiled it using the cygwin `g++` compiler in Win7.  I am now trying to debug the resulting executable in gdb, but I can't get it to behave the way I expect it to.  I cannot place breakpoints because when I try to execute `b file.cpp:25` I get back

```
No source file named file.cpp.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])
```

I select y and it still does not break at the expected point.  I did compile from this source.

I am getting a segfault at a certain point and `whe` also does not actually show line numbers.  It seems to show memory addresses, which is obviously not useful to me.

Is gdb is misbehaving or am i just expecting it to do things it can't do?  If it doesn't have this capability (though I've done this kind of thing before), is there another tool I can use?

Comment: Did you add the `-g` option when compiling? It tells the compiler to add debug information.

Comment: @izomorphius cygwin `gdb` doesn't recognize `-g` as a valid option

Comment: @ewok feed g++ with that option not gdb....

Comment: @izomorphius thanks.  post as an answer so I can accept

Comment: And this info can help "How do I use gcc, g++, and gdb?" (http://www.seas.upenn.edu/cets/answers/gcc.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add debug information during compilation you should use the `-g` flag for g++.